# Creating NuGet hierarchy based on OS

Tags: c#, dependencies, nuget

I'm struggling with this for some time now: I have a nuget that needs to run native code, different binary for each OS (I support Windows, OSX, Linux-X64, Linux-Arm64 and Linux-Alpine).

I currently deploy all the binaries bundled in the same nuget, but since each binary is big (~80-90MB) I want to separate the binaries to sub-nugets, but I don't want the end-users to be affected by this change, so they can still refer to "MyNuget". In order for it to be effective I want it to only restore the relevant sub-nuget according to the OS.

I tried adding conditionals to the `ProjectReference`s but when I publish the nugets the conditionals are removed and I left with the platform I built on.

I also tried creating `.nuspec` manually but could't figure out the correct way to set conditonals, and the same goes for `.targets` file.

I think this is possible, since I remember seeing projects which do this (unfortunately I can't remember which projects or how to reverse-engineer a nuget package to its source), but not much documentation is available for the HOW to do it.

To sum up, the structure I'm trying to achieve:

```
Layer 1: OS-specific cores
[Core.Linux.X64]/[Core.Linux.Arm64]/[Core.Windows.X64]/[Core.OSX]/...
```

```
Layer 2: Core selector
   |
   +--> Layer 1
```

```
Layer 3: MyNuget
   |
   +--> Layer 2
```

```
Layer 4: End-User app
```

I want to be able to publish the first 3 layers as nugets and let the user (layer 4) only add `PackageRefernce` to `MyNuget` (layer 3) and it'll use the core-selector (layer 2) to restore automatically the correct core (layer 1) according to the OS the user is building on.

References to docs and working examples will be much appreciated.